What's the correct way to re-export namespace in TypeScript while adding a few properties to it?
I want to re-export zod namespace, but add a few properties to it.
I tried this:
import * as zod from 'zod';

export namespace z {
  export * from 'zod';

  export const numericId = () => zod.coerce.number().int().safe();
}

However, this approach is giving TypeScript error:

Export declarations are not permitted in a namespace.ts(1194)

It also fails to bundle using ESBuild with an error:

Unexpected "export"

I was able to make it partially work using this approach:
export namespace z {
  // @ts-expect-error - TODO TypeScript complains that export is not allowed. However, it works.
  export type * from 'zod';

  export const string = zod.string;

  export const numericId = () => zod.coerce.number().int().safe();
}

But ran into limitation that export const enum and export const null is not allowed because the variable names are reserved.
export const { array, boolean, enum, null, number, object, string, record, literal, union } = zod;

(^This does work because null and enum cannot be exported as variables)

Why use a namespace? You can just export everything from zod using a wildcard export, including your extensions (values and types), then import it in another module using a wildcard import (example). See Namespaces and Modules in the TS handbook. Does that meet your needs? If so, I can write an answer — if not, what did I miss?

Because I want to retain compatibility with the existing zod package interface, which exports a namespace.

^ @LilouArtz Can you elaborate on that concern? What kind of "compatibility" are you worried about losing by using ES modules instead of namespaces?

I want to use my abstraction the same way that I would reference zod imports if I were to use zod package directly.

^ @LilouArtz Alright, but you still haven't explained… what would not be compatible about (re-)exporting from a module when compared to using a namespace? (Did you try the code that I previously suggested?) Please [edit] the question to clarify the concern.

I don't see how my explanation is lacking. Re-exporting namespace is necessary to achieve equivalent behavior of zod. Without it, I cannot reference types and or methods exported, just like with zod.
e.g. import {z} from 'zod'; z.ZodIssue; z.number(). Both should work.

Don't use namespaces. Write a module:
export * from 'zod';
import { coerce } from 'zod';

export const numericId = () => coerce.number().int().safe();

